# How can I send string data from activity to fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I have modular app. Its 'app' module has a fragment and it calls activity in different module. Then with a back button I want to return to my fragment with a string data. But it enters loop after a while.

This fragment code is in 'app' module where I call the activity:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        button_info_idcard.setOnClickListener {
            //start OcrActivity
            //Toast.makeText(context, "fdglkds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(activity, OcrActivity::class.java)
            (activity as MainActivity2?)!!.startActivityForResult(intent, 101)
        }
    }
```

This activity code is in different module where I try to return fragment and enter the loop:

```
imagebutton_ocr_back.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent()
            intent.putExtra("TEST_TEXT",test)
            setResult(101,intent)
            finish()
        }
```

If data comes from activity I want to see as a Toast message on screen:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        Log.i("Muhittin","onActivityResult()")

        if (requestCode == 101) {
            val message = data!!.getStringExtra("TEST_TEXT")
            Toast.makeText(context,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

**Note:** I cannot directly call fragment in activity because it causes 'circular dependency' which is architectural problem in modular structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change

```
(activity as MainActivity2?)!!.startActivityForResult(intent, 101)
```

to

```
startActivityForResult(intent, 101)
```

because if you using `activity.startActivityForResult()` intent will call `onActivityResult()` in activity class